# Multivariable Calculus Linear Approximation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having a problem with the question:

Use the linear approximation of 
$f(x, y) = e^{2x^2+3y}$ at $(0, 0)$ to estimate $f(0.01, -0.02)$.

I know how to take linear approximations with one variable by taking the derivative, but I am a bit lost on how to do this with two variables (partial differentiation I think). I have tried many things but I am unable to get the correct answer. Later on in this assignment, a third variable is introduced. Could somebody please help me through this problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hint: what are the slopes in each of the $x$ and $y$ directions? The first-order approximation for several variables is like a combination of one-variable approximations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \,dx+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\, dy. \tag{This is a chain rule.}
$$
$$
\Delta f \approx \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \,\Delta x+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\, \Delta y.
$$
$$
f(0+\Delta x,0+\Delta y) = f(0,0) + \Delta f.
$$
\begin{align}
f(0,0) & =1 \\
\Delta x & = 0.01 \\
\Delta y & = -0.02.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

With one dependent variable we use the tangent line to approximate, with two dependent variables we use the tangent plane to approximate. The tangent plane has a normal vector of $\langle 1,0,f_x \rangle \times  \langle 0,1,f_y \rangle=\langle -f_x,-f_y,1 \rangle$.

Hence the equation of the tangent plane at a point $(a,b,c)$ is:

$$-f_x(a,b)(x-a)-f_y(a,b)(y-b)+1(z-c)=0$$

Dividing by $-1$ on both sides and solving for $z$ we get:

$$f_x(a,b)(x-a)+f_y(a,b)(y-b)+c=z$$

Substituting values of $(x,y)$ near $(a,b)$ will give us an approximation of $z(x,y)$.